# cannot load --faker for heroku installation

Tags: heroku, rake, faker

I am trying to run heroku rake db:migrate and keep running into the same problem. It says it cannot load a file --faker. I tried putting this in my gem file in every possible way. Here's my gem file right now:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
end

group :test do 
    gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.4'
    gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.9'
    gem 'autotest', '4.3.2'
    gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.0'
    gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

no matter what I do it won't load the faker file so I can complete the heroku install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need to use faker on Heroku? Isn't it more for loading data during development? Did you try putting it in your development group?

Also, take a look at this post [heroku rake db:migrate > no such file to load -- faker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013826/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-no-such-file-to-load-faker)

Comment: Yes, I tried all solutions on that page. Also, faker was initially in my dev group and it gave the same issue. I tried removing it all together...no luck. I actually just removed every mention of "faker" in my entire project and it still gives the same error.

Comment: you've removed it entirely and it still errors? Did you do a project wide search for references to faker and commit changes before pushing  up to Heroku?