# LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffaker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Please forgive my ignorance. I'm having issues raking my database on heroku. When I run :

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffaker
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/lib/tasks/seed.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:241:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `bl
ock in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `ea
ch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `ru
n_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:384:i
n `run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:449:in `lo
ad_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `p
ublic_send'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `m
ethod_missing'
/app/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've tried following the solutions from [heroku rake db:migrate > no such file to load -- faker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013826/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-no-such-file-to-load-faker) with no luck. I really am not sure where else to go from here. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify this in your code:

```
require 'ffaker'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you have ffaker in the right gem group. I was setting up a staging environment and wanted to load dummy data and forgot ffaker was only in development and testing environment groups.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the git URL to add `ffaker` in my Gemfile. I removed this URL, run bundle again and everything works ok now.

```
-  gem 'ffaker', '~>2.10.0', git: 'https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker.git'
+  gem 'ffaker', '~>2.10.0'
```